# Eclipse BIRT report element width adjustments following orientation change

Tags: eclipse, birt

I've developed a BIRT report in landscape orientation and now need to have it in portrait. When I change the master page orientation to portrait the page dimensions change but the elements are still taking the old widths (crossing the page border) and I'm not able to manually adjust their widths. Is there a way to re-adjust all the elements to fit within the new page dimensions?

Comment: Can you expand on not being able to "adjust their widths"?  Adjusting column width is fairly simple, Select the table, select the column > Properties > General, clear or enter a new value for column width.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean is that you cannot see the columns in the UI and thus cannot change their widths.

But you can switch to the XML source window and modify the widths from there:

First, give your table a meaningful name if you haven't already done.
Then locate the table element in the XML (hint: search for the name).
Inside the  element there are  elements and there you'll find the widths and can edit them. In addition, the table also has a width which you should edit.
Depending on the complexity of your layout structure, this can get tedious work.

Note that you can also *clear* the width (*for the table **and** some or all of the columns*). The columns with no explicit width then share the space not occupied by the columns with explicit widths). This is a very handy feature of BIRT.

Answer (score 0):

Set the page layout preference to Auto layout

```
<property name="layoutPreference">auto layout</property>
```

Then check the elements you are using to verify that they are able to resize. For example a grid can have its width set to 100% (instead of a fixed size) and has an option "Can shrink". You can also set the columns to percentage sizes.

If it is a chart, make it small and then add some script to resize it to fill the container on rendering (add to the onContentUpdate event). For example, you could add:

```
var reportWidth = this.getViewer().getWidth();
var reportHeight = this.getViewer().getHeight();
var chart = this.getViewer().getChart();
chart.getClientChart().setSize(reportWidth, reportHeight);
```